# How to convert a PDF to DOC/DOCX in linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, docx, file-conversion

I'm trying to convert several PDF files to MS Word files (.doc|.docx) in Ubuntu Server, I've tried LibreOffice but it doesn't respect the typography of the PDF file, I've found an online tool that converts PDF to DOC/DOCX perfectly, the result they give is exactly what I'm looking for (http://pdf2docx.com/). Does anyone know how I can get similar results in my own server?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3):

I've had pretty good luck using Abiword to do the conversion:

```
sudo apt-get install abiword
abiword --to=doc whatever.pdf
```

Comment: When executing
`abiword --to=doc mydoc.pdf`
I'm getting this error
`** (abiword:31833): WARNING **: clutter failed 0, get a life.`

Comment: abiword cannot handle the format properly. It may only capture normal paragraph text, but not the heading, and hyperlinks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be that reliable especially as it either generates a blank document or one with just *unformatted* text.